# How do I get firefox to forget last opened tabs during startup?

Tags: firefox

When I open up firefox it always remembers all of my previous tabs and opens all of them up again the next time I start it up. Is there a way to change this behavior and make it only open up one tab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "General" tab in Firefox' settings there's an option to choose what happens when firefox starts.

[image: Firefox Settings]

[image: Firefox options]

From the drop-down you can change the option to one of the following:

- Show my home page
- Show a blank page

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Options >> General >> Startup*  and change the drop down setting next to *When Firefox Starts:* to *Show My Homepage* then input your desired page into the edit box below that.